# Hide Action Extension from Chrome in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

I have an app for iOS 8 which includes an Action Extension. This extension requires JavaScript code to work properly (both to get information from the web page and also to execute actions inside it). That works perfect with the Safari browser but not with Chrome. The problem is that Chrome added support for extensions, but not for JavaScript communication ([reference](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=405894)).

Because of that, I would like to make it so that my extension will not be available when the user is navigating from within Chrome. How should I setup the activation rules for my extension to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case I have removed below properties from the extension plist. Now it's not showing in chrome and note app.

1. NSExtensionActivationSupportsText
2. NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebPageWithMaxCount.